# gitlab ssh access connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to access gitlab with my account in SSH with public key authentication. I have uploaded my public key and here is my SSH configuration:

```
content of /home/$my_user/.ssh/config
Host gitlab
User git
Port 22
Hostname gitlab.$my_domain
IdentityFile /home/$my_user/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Here is the command I tiped:

```
mkdir $my_project
cd $my_project
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin gitlab:$my_user/$my_project.git
git push -u origin master
```

Here is the sshd log file:
[auth.log](http://pastebin.com/twpAC9ZD)

Here is the stack on client side:
[client stack](http://pastebin.com/Uztp1NZN)

As I am authenticated, and my key correctly loaded from ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys, I presume the trouble comes from the client side. But I cannot determine where the issue comes from and neither how to fix it.

Many thanks for your help; Don't hesitate to ask for more details if you need to.

EDIT: [here](http://pastebin.com/ptevi5QY) is the output of ssh -v git@gitlab

Comment: What is the output of "ssh -v git@gitlab"

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I posted the pastbin link of the output of ssh -v git@gitlab as an edit of my post

Comment: Have you run `rake gitlab:check` as described at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide and corrected any problems it finds?

Comment: I think you should add the outputs of your commands here. The links no longer work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gitlab shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell), which is invoked by your SSH login, needs to make a call to the [API](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/api) of the [gitlab web application](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) to determine if you're authorized to push. However, it can't connect to it. Run the appropriate [rake task](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/#rake-tasks) for your version of gitlab to check the configuration of all the gitlab components and fix any errors it finds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which resolves the issue I was having. Running the rake task according to my gitlab version (sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production) shows that there was a trouble with my host which is named differently from inside or outside my network. I remapped it to always point to my internal hostname (/etc/hosts) and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

A 'Connection Refused' message generally means that there is no process listening on the IP:Port combination you are trying to connect to.

- Confirm the ports that you are using.
- Use netstat to check that processes are listening on the relevant IP:ports.
- Check that you are not blocking the ports at your firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however SSH port is open, its banner shows up and ssh-server fingerprints get displayed; sciurus advice helped me understand that the different names associated to the server (from inside or outside the network) was causing the trouble. I have launched ``sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`` which showed the error.

Comment: @philippe I guess I was kinda right in that it wasn't listening on the IP:port you were connecting t ;)

Comment: You were totally right, but I couldn't retrieve the answer from it, I was convinced the issue would come from a network trouble; It was indeed a network issue, but caused by a wrong configuration.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is due to git/https buffer settings. In order to solve it

```
  git config http.postBuffer somehugenumber
```

And run the command again

Comment: Thanks for your help; I have tried launching ``git config http.postBuffer 524288000``; with same result :/